# Select count from one table, and columns from another ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have two tables, Staff and Cust_Order. I want to add the column 'First name' from the staff table
while still performing the below code:

```sql
Select Staff_No Count(*) AS "Number Of Orders"
From Cust_Order 
Group by Staff_No;
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the orders and staff tables, then group by will need to include the additional column(s)

```
SELECT
      co.Staff_No
    , s.First_name
    , COUNT(*) AS "Number Of Orders"
FROM Cust_Order co
INNER JOIN Staff s on co.Staff_No = s.Staff_No
GROUP BY
      co.Staff_No
    , s.First_name
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   STAFF_NO,
   FIRST_NAME,
   COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY STAFF_NO) AS "Number Of Orders"
FROM CUST_ORDER;
```

Used distinct as there might be duplicate results in case first_name is not unique.

Comment: sorry, but distinct isn't the way to do this, tip: count() is an aggregation function associated with group by....

Comment: Did you even try this solution? Count is used as an analytic function here.

Answer (score 0):

Get the count as a sub query

```
Select First_Name,
 (Select Count(*) From Cust_Order o 
      Where o.STAFF_NO = Cust_Order.STAFF_NO)  "Number Of Orders"
From Cust_Order
```